# Spring Boot Thymeleaf pagination

Tags: html, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I got stuck at resolving this problem with pagination. When i trying to get on index page i getting this message

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Exception evaluating SpringEL expression:
>   "#numbers.sequence(0,page.totalPages-1" (template: "index" - line 36,
>   col 38)

And in debug i found this specific line

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [#numbers.sequence(0,page.totalPages-1] @17: EL1051E: Unexpectedly ran out of arguments
```

Pagination

```
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item" th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0,data.totalPages-1}">
                    <a th:href="@{/(page=${i})}" th:text="${i}" class="nav-link"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPage(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page){
        model.addAttribute("data",phonebookRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page,4)));
        model.addAttribute("currentPage",page);
        return "index";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parentheses

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li class="nav-item" th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0,data.totalPages-1)}">
      <a th:href="@{/(page=${i})}" th:text="${i}" class="nav-link"></a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```